# How to install two keyboard layouts (Korean/English) and switch between them?

Tags: keyboard, language, input

I set to 1) system } keboard } insert to korea+english 2) korea selected } layout change: shift+CapsLock 3) enghlist selected } layout change: shift+CapsLock

i want to language change at press shift+capsLock. but, my computer is only english. How do I set it up?

Answer (score 1):

`Shift+ Caps Lock` shortcut does work well if you set it to switch your keyboard layouts, I checked on that. However, to be able to actually type with Korean  characters instead of Latin ones, in addition to Korean keyboard layout you have to install **additional input method** (Korean Hangul). On how to do that in Ubuntu-based OS, please refer to [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456133/unable-to-type-in-korean).

In elementary OS you can also access this feature via the `Input Method Settings...` button in the bottom right corner of the `System Settings > Keyboard` panel.